# Why doesn't the Graph Editor show my keyframes and connecting lines

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I have a Graph Editor open alongside the dopesheet, as you can see in the screenshot (following). The Graph Editor is not showing my keyframes or the connecting lines. I have checked to make sure the eye icon is turned on. I have also check in the previously asked questions and didn't find an answer. This seems really simple, but I don't know what else to do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen shot is a little low res, so it's hard to see.

Your keyframes in the dope sheet are in the 340 to 410 range but the graph editor is set to show the -200 to 200 frame range.

I think if you press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key while the cursor is in the graph editor the view should zoom to your keyframes.

Alternatively your keyframes are simply out of view on the y-axis of the graph editor and the <kbd>Home</kbd> will also solve this.

Comment: Thank you. I understand what you mean about the range. I looked all around and tried different things before I took the screenshot. Sorry for the low-res. It is what it is. I do the best I can with what I've got. I solved it.I needed to select "View Selected" from the View menu in the Graph editor. I've never had to do that before so I'm not sure if it was changed in the factory settings in 2.71. I recently updated, so I figure that's the most likely explanation.

(https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10204231949056051&set=a.10204231459683817.1073741845.1147304074&type=3&theater)

Answer (score 0):

*The item under view menu in graph editor is missing/not there anymore in v.2.92.
I had to do the same thing of 'Show only selected channels' but from the timeline panel. Posting just in case someone else has the same issue.*

Edit: Oops. That is incorrect, I had to first do that in timeline but the keyframes still didn't show up in Graph Editor. The actual way to unhide it was under the 'Filter' button in Graph editor menu.